# How do I find where the 301 redirect is for this error loop?

Tags: nginx, php, amazon-web-services, .htaccess

I am getting redirect loop / endless chain and I cannot figure it out. I'm very new to programming and servers so please help someone very green! Here is what I have so far:

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Route

```
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'get.site', 'uses' => 'SiteController@getHome'
]);
```

Controller

```
public function getHome() {
   $this->model['title'] = 'Home Page';
   $this->model['description'] = 'Welcome to my home Page';

   return $this->renderView('home');
}
```

Here is my nginx file:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/before/*;

server_tokens off;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://assets.zendesk.com https://connect.facebook.net; img-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://assets.zendesk.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://assets.zendesk.com; font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com; frame-src https://assets.zendesk.com https://www.facebook.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://tautt.zendesk.com; object-src 'none'";

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;    
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/forge/example.com;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
     ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/server.cr;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/server.key;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/188983/server.crt;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload;";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;
    #SET REAL IP
    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    set_real_ip_from 10.0.1.174;

    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/example.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    #error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {         
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        #try_files $uri =404;
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }      

}
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/after/*;
```

Response Headers for http://example.com:

```
URL:
http://example.com
http/1.1 301 moved permanently
server: nginx/1.11.9
date: Sun, 09 Jul 2017 23:53:40 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 185
connection: keep-alive
location: https://example.com/

Redirecting URL:
https://example.com/
http/1.1 301 moved permanently
server: nginx/1.11.9
date: Sun, 09 Jul 2017 23:53:41 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 178
connection: keep-alive
location: http://example.com/
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
referrer-policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://assets.zendesk.com https://connect.facebook.net; img-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://assets.zendesk.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://assets.zendesk.com; font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com; frame-src https://assets.zendesk.com https://www.facebook.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://tautt.zendesk.com; object-src 'none'
```

Response Headers for https://example.com

```
URL:
https://example.com
http/1.1 301 moved permanently
server: nginx/1.11.9
date: Sun, 09 Jul 2017 23:56:58 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 178
connection: keep-alive
location: http://example.com/
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
referrer-policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://assets.zendesk.com https://connect.facebook.net; img-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://assets.zendesk.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://assets.zendesk.com; font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com; frame-src https://assets.zendesk.com https://www.facebook.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://tautt.zendesk.com; object-src 'none'

Redirecting URL:
http://example.com/
http/1.1 301 moved permanently
server: nginx/1.11.9
date: Sun, 09 Jul 2017 23:56:58 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 185
connection: keep-alive
location: https://example.com/
```

Comment: What is the point using both nginx and Apache in your setup? I think that is plain overhead and you should get rid of either one. You should try adding HTTP headers in your application code to see, where exactly the HTTP redirect is sent. If you see the application set HTTP header in the Curl output, then you know the issue is in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem section is this one:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://$host$request_uri;
}
```

The scheme variable contains the scheme that was used to connect to this server. Since this server block only listens on port 80, scheme will always be `http`. That means that this block always redirects to itself. To fix this, simply change `$scheme` to `https`:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although, it didn't solve anything, I get the same result...a redirect loop.

Comment: @user2998254 did you restart nginx after changing the config?

Comment: @user2998254, did it fix your issue??

Comment: I would agree, that did look like a problem, however, it doesn't explain the apparent response the OP is getting which appears to be bouncing between HTTP and HTTPS, ie. HTTP to HTTPS to HTTP to HTTPS etc. In the absence of any further (server) config files, this perhaps looks like an application/PHP issue?

Comment: @Jadeye We never did figure it out, we thought the same thing, must be an application issue but nothing was coming up. It was taking too much time, so we ended up creating new instances and moved the application over and now everything working fine. I really appreciate your help in trying to solve it.